# Xcode not finding Afnetworking file in my project

Tags: ios, xcode6, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I downloaded Afnetworking zip file and and then drag and drop the UIkit+ Afnetworking and Afnetworking foler in my project. I am not using pods. But when i try to include #import "AFNetworking.h" file, its showing me a folder sign with `Afnetworking\`. I am using xcode 6.4.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot Link https://www.dropbox.com/s/2em9tsn0yu2vnem/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-17%20at%201.51.21%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: You can  create a new group in project navigator and drag afnetworking folders in that new group.

Answer (score 0):

Copy while dragging and dropping files in your project navigator.

Comment: I copied while dragging and dropping. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

While adding folder into project make sure `Create groups` is selected. Below is the screen shot

[image]